# Android : Previous activity textboxes retain their value

Tags: android

I am new to android development. When returning to previous activity by pressing back button, previous activity textboxes are not blank. They retain their values. How to start a previous activity as a new activity without using startActivity() function?

Comment: post your code . so that i can see what you deed . and provide a proper solution.

Comment: If the only thing you want is empty `TextViews`, why not set the fields to empty in your `OnResume()`? This way you dont have to keep recreating the activity.

Comment: there are multiple textboxes and multiple forms for which i want to do this. So setting each textboxes to empty will not be good solution I think.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your previous activity

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Either use finish(); or u can use textbox.setText("");

Comment: aint there a solution for every time a activity starts or resumes it starts as a fresh activity.

Comment: If u want to start a activity as a fresh activity why don't u give startActivity() function?

Answer (score 0):

Either finish your activity when exiting it (when navigating to other functions...

Or use the onResume function to handle any modification to that activity state

```
onResume(){
   if(aFlag){
      TextView yourText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXTVIEW_ID);
      yourText.setText("");
   }
}
```

Comment: if finishing the activity on exiting the back button take me back to the parent of the previous activity as the previous activity is not on the stack.